# Can't record or play with a simple recorder?

Tags: objective-c

I have **2** classes, a record and a player. In my main scene, I create an instance of them and play and record. But, as I see, it only records and somehow does not play (the file is not there!)

Here is the code for both :

```
-(void)record {
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSString *sound= @"sound0.caf" ;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:sound];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
      [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
      [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
      [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],
      AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];

    NSError *error;
    myRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:settings error:&error];

    if (myRecorder)  {
        NSLog(@"rec");
        [myRecorder prepareToRecord];
        myRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [myRecorder record];
    } else
        NSLog( @"error"  );
}
```

**I can see the log of** `rec`.

```
-(void)play {
  NSArray *dirPaths;
  NSString *docsDir;
  dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *soundFilePath1 =  @"sound0.caf" ;
  NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath1];
  BOOL isMyFileThere = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundFilePath1];
  if(isMyFileThere) {
    NSLog(@"PLAY"); 
    avPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:NULL];
    avPlayer1.volume = 8.0;
    avPlayer1.delegate = self;
    [avPlayer1 play];
 }
}
```

**I DONT SEE THE LOG OF** `PLAY` !

I call them both with:

```
recInst=[recorder alloc]; //to rec
[recInst record];

plyInst=[player alloc]; //play
[plyInst play];
```

and to stop the recorder:

```
- (void)stopRecorder {
    NSLog(@"stopRecordings");
    [myRecorder stop];
    //[myRecorder release];    
}
```

What's wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your record method, you're appending the file name to the path with:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound0.caf"];
```

You do not do that in your play method, so it's looking for the file in whatever the current working directory is, rather than the Documents directory.

You need to do:

```
NSString *soundFilePath1 = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound0.caf"];
```

instead of:

```
NSString *soundFilePath1 =  @"sound0.caf" ;
```

And just another note:  soundFilePath and soundFilePath1 are both local variables.  Therefore, they are not visible outside their respective methods.  Thus, it's not necessary to give them different names.  You can call them both soundFilePath and there will not be a conflict.